# how to read JSON object using volley

Tags: android, json, gson, android-volley

In the json link I have, it contains the property called `products`, it is an array that contains several  objects. How can I read that property `products` and iterate through each element in it? For example how to get the value of id, color and price? I tried the following but it seems that this line

```
Response.Listener<JSONObject> onPostsLoaded
```

does not accept `JSONObject` as type

Please let me know how to read an json object using volley

```
 private void initGson() {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("M/d/yy hh:mm a");
    gson = gsonBuilder.create();
}

private void doRetrofit() {
    API_BASE_URL = this.getResources().getString(R.string.BASE_URL);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    fetchPosts();
}

private void fetchPosts() {
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, API_BASE_URL, onPostsLoaded, onPostsError);
    requestQueue.add(request);
}

private final Response.Listener<JSONObject> onPostsLoaded = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.i(TAG, response);

        response.getJs
        //List<Repo> repos = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(response, Repo[].class));

        /*Log.i("PostActivity", repos.size() + " posts loaded.");
        for (Repo repo : repos) {
            //Log.i("PostActivity", repo.getImageUrl() + ": " + repo.getName());
        }*/
    }
};

private final Response.ErrorListener onPostsError = new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e(TAG, error.toString());
    }
};
```

**JSON**:

```
 products: [
 {
     name: "Yellow Triangle",
     type: "Triangle",
     id: 1,
     color: "Yellow",
     imageURL: "https://kredit.check24.de/konto- 
     kredit/ratenkredit/nativeapps/imgs/08.png",
     colorCode: "FFECB3",
     available: true,
     releaseDate: 1460629605,
     description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
sed diam",
     longDescription: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
elitr, sed diam Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
elitr, sed diam Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
elitr, sed diam Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
elitr, sed diam",
     rating: 2.17,
     price: {
         value: 225.91,
         currency: "EUR"
         }
    },
```

Comment: You want a JsonObjectRequest, not StringRequest

Comment: If you would like to use Gson, though see https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom#example-gsonrequest

Comment: @cricket_007 should i also change this line         JsonObjectRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, API_BASE_URL, onPostsLoaded, onPostsError);
??

Comment: `new JsonObjectRequest`, not a StringRequest

Answer (score 0):

You should [start with the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request#request-json). Rather than pulling out the listeners manually, you can use the IDE to extract those for you.

The type of the listener is what's being responded with.

You're telling it to respond with a JSON Object, but the method doesn't implement the correct signature

This should compile

```
private final Response.Listener<JSONObject> onPostsLoaded = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(response));
```

And since you have Gson, [see it's usage in the documentation with Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom#example-gsonrequest)

Comment: i still have error in : private void fetchPosts() {
        JsonObjectRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, API_BASE_URL, onPostsLoaded, onPostsError);
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }......this line is marked with red: StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, API_BASE_URL, onPostsLoaded, onPostsError);

Comment: You can't assign a StringRequest object to a JsonObjectRequest variable

Comment: fine. i chnaged it..but i have error still, please help.error at the same line:         JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, API_BASE_URL, onPostsLoaded, onPostsError);

Comment: Add `null` parameter after the url

Answer (score 0):

You choose wrong data types. Change your code as follow :

```
private void fetchPosts() {
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, API_BASE_URL, onPostsLoaded, onPostsError);
    requestQueue.add(request);
}

private final Response.Listener<String> onPostsLoaded = new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

        // use obj to get your data
    }
};
```

When there is `Response.Listener<JSONObject>`, you have a `JSONObject` in response :

```
Response.Listener<String>     ----->    public void onResponse(String response)
Response.Listener<JSONObject> ----->    public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
```

Comment: If that string is always JSON, then just using JsonObjectRequest makes more sense, though

Comment: maybe you can answert his question please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824361/how-to-iterate-through-json-array-using-volley-and-gson

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
      Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,"api_link", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            JSONObject mJsonObject;

            try {
                JSONArray mJsonArray=new JSONArray(s)
                JSONArray mJsonArray1 = mJsonArray.getJSONArray("products");
                int a = mJsonArray1.length();
                for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                    JSONObject jo = mJsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                    homeModel.setID(jo.getString("color"));
                    //AND add somthing code u want

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And my HomeModel list :

```
 public class HomeModel {
public String ID;
public String pic;
public String color;

public String getcolor() {
    return color;
}

 public String setcolor(String color) {
   this.color=String color
   }

 }
```

Comment: if  dont work tell me mb i mistaje to pars JSONARRAY

Comment: maybe you can answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824361/how-to-iterate-through-json-array-using-volley-and-gson